# Constraint for values with different labels when all other columns are equal

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, constraints, multiple-columns

I would like to create a constraint that verifies if a value (from the 'nominal_value' column) classified as "minimum" in the 'stats_type' column is equal or smaller than a value classified as "average", when all values in the other columns are equal. In other words, given corresponding tuples, except for columns 'oid', 'stats_type' and 'nominal_value', I'd like to ensure the value labeled "minimum" is always equal or smaller than the value labeled as "average".

It is difficult to explain, so I made the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE price (
    oid SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    product INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    territory INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    stats_type INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    nominal_value NUMERIC(6,2)  NOT NULL,
    data_source INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_price PRIMARY KEY (oid),
    CONSTRAINT price_1 UNIQUE (product, territory, stats_type, year, data_source),
    CONSTRAINT price_2 CHECK (nominal_value > 0)
);

INSERT INTO price (oid, product, territory, stats_type, year, nominal_value, data_source) VALUES (1, 55, 5611, 1, 2014, 120, 3);
INSERT INTO price (oid, product, territory, stats_type, year, nominal_value, data_source) VALUES (2, 55, 5611, 2, 2014, 160, 3);
INSERT INTO price (oid, product, territory, stats_type, year, nominal_value, data_source) VALUES (3, 55, 5615, 1, 2014, 60, 3);
INSERT INTO price (oid, product, territory, stats_type, year, nominal_value, data_source) VALUES (4, 55, 5611, 3, 2014, 180, 3);
INSERT INTO price (oid, product, territory, stats_type, year, nominal_value, data_source) VALUES (5, 62, 5615, 1, 2013, 1500, 3);
INSERT INTO price (oid, product, territory, stats_type, year, nominal_value, data_source) VALUES (6, 62, 5615, 2, 2013, 1300, 3);
```

The 'stats_type' labels are: 1 = minimum, 2 = average, 3 = maximum.

Looking at the first two rows; they are equal, except for 'oid', 'stats_type' and 'nominal_value'; so I'd like to verify: is 120 (which is labeled as minimum in the first row) smaller or equal than 160 (the value labeled as average)? In this case the answer is yes, so it passed the verification.

Now, the last two rows (5 and 6) also have a match regarding columns 'product', 'territory', 'year' and 'data_source'. However, it happens that the nominal value 1500 in row 5 should not be smaller than 1300 in row 6 (because 1500 was supposed to be minimum, and 1300 an average value).

How can I do this? Is it possible to accomplish such task using a 'check' constraint?

Comment: _Is it possible to accomplish such task using a 'check' constraint?_ No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done using a check constraint because of necessity of querying the table. You can use a trigger:

```
create or replace function price_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if exists (
        select 1
        from price p
        where (p.product, p.territory, p.year, p.data_source) = 
              (new.product, new.territory, new.year, new.data_source)
        and (
            p.stats_type < new.stats_type and p.nominal_value > new.nominal_value
            or
            p.stats_type > new.stats_type and p.nominal_value < new.nominal_value
            )
        )
    then
        raise exception 'Nominal value error';
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger price_trigger
before insert or update on price
for each row
execute procedure price_trigger();
```

The trigger function checks all conditions (min < avg < max).

Comment: This function does the job. But in his scenario the last two insertions were problematic, you don't know if the problem was with the average or the minimum value. The trigger will only prevent the last insertion. If he does the insertion in one single statement, then he can use a trigger with "FOR STATEMENT" modifier, instead of ROW modifier.

Comment: It's easy to make the function more verbose but I doubt it's necessary. Obviously the function **cannot** be used as statement-level trigger because you need an access to inserted (updated) values.

Answer (score 1):

Since your scenario has the complexity that the insertions can be made in any order, I suggest that you perform the insertions in a secondary table beforehand, such as price_check.

Then you could put a trigger to perform a SQL such as:

```
SELECT pmin.* 
FROM price_check AS pmin
JOIN price_check AS pavg
    ON (pmin.product, pmin.territory, pmin.year, pmin.data_source) = (pavg.product, pavg.territory, pavg.year, pavg.data_source)
        AND pmin.stats_type = 1 
        AND pavg.stats_type = 2
        AND pmin.nominal_value <= pavg.nominal_value
```

Which will return valid minimum only and use this to perform the insertion on the final table. Be aware that I use an INNER JOIN, so minimum without an average pair won't return, you would have to use a LEFT JOIN to do so.

Similarly, you can design queries on price_check put non-valid rows in a price_log table to manually check them latter on.

Alternatively you could put an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on your table without need for the secondary table, but even so it is a good practice to create a LOG table to manually check and fix non-valid rows.

Comment: Since your insertions are stepwise and the 1st value you inserted can be the problematic one, I suggest you to use the secondary table approach. The trigger will only detect the problem after you already inserted 1st and the 2nd value, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a postgresql function for all inserts/updates (or upserts) on the table. Then you can use case logic to identify what can go in, and specify real API status return codes for incorrect input data events. You can write it in PL/pgSQL, or python or any other extendable language in postgres that you're comfortable in.

ex.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION band.usp_band_add_update(
i_sess TEXT,
i_ban_name TEXT,
i_ban_email TEXT,
i_ban_description TEXT,
i_geo_id BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE(
band_id BIGINT,
status_id INT,
status_desc TEXT
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
_user BIGINT;
_ban_id BIGINT;
_status_id INT;
_status_desc TEXT;
_pass TEXT;
BEGIN

SELECT asr_user 
  INTO _user
  FROM sess.usp_sess_check(i_sess);

IF _user IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT ban_id 
      FROM band.band
     WHERE ban_user = _user
      INTO _ban_id;
    IF _ban_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE band.band 
           SET ban_name = i_ban_name,
               ban_description = i_ban_description,
               ban_geo_id = i_geo_id,
               ban_modified = now()
         WHERE ban_user = _user;
        _status_id = 200;
        _status_desc = 'ban_id updated: ' || _ban_id::text;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO band.band (ban_user, ban_name, ban_email, ban_description, ban_geo_id)
        VALUES (_user, i_ban_name, i_ban_email, i_ban_description, i_geo_id)
        RETURNING ban_id INTO _ban_id;
        _status_id = 200;
        _status_desc = 'ban_id inserted: ' ||  _ban_id::text;
    END IF;
ELSE
    _status_id = 402;
    _status_desc = 'User does not exist.';
END IF;
RETURN QUERY SELECT _ban_id, _status_id, _status_desc;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I followed your answer. Did you provide an example based on another dataset you had?

Comment: yes. The answer is not in your data format. It's just an example for syntax purposes.